# Handling the event in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard-events

I am making a game in which the user has to press a specific key to make the player move. During the handling of this event, which one is the correct code to be written :-

```
if event.type == pygame.K_E:
      vel_F1_x = 2
      vel_F2_x = 0
```

OR

```
   if event.type == pygame.K_e:
       vel_F1_x = 2
       vel_F2_x = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enumeration constant for the key <kbd>e</kbd> is `K_e`. However, none of your code snippets is correct.

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released.
The key that was pressed can be obtained from the `key` attribute of the [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object:

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
     if event.key == pygame.K_e:
         vel_F1_x = 2
         vel_F2_x = 0
```

---

If you want to evaluate whether a key is being held down, use `pygame.key.get_pressed()`.

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.
[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed():
if keys[pygame.K_e]:
    # [...]
```